# indexOfValue(E) of SparseArrayCompat always return -1?

Tags: android, sparse-array

`indexOfValue(E)` method always return -1 while I am sure my `E` object exists in my `SparseArray` object, why? I have :

```
static final SparseArrayCompat<Long> LOCATION_SHARING_TIME = new SparseArrayCompat<Long>();
static {
    LOCATION_SHARING_TIME.put(0, LOCATION_SHARING_TIME_5s);
    LOCATION_SHARING_TIME.put(1, LOCATION_SHARING_TIME_1m);
    LOCATION_SHARING_TIME.put(2, LOCATION_SHARING_TIME_5m);
    LOCATION_SHARING_TIME.put(3, LOCATION_SHARING_TIME_30m);
    LOCATION_SHARING_TIME.put(4, LOCATION_SHARING_TIME_1h);
}
```

I cannot use SparseLongArray because it support API 18+ which my project support API 9 minimum.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because it uses == instead of equal to determine the equality. See the implementation of the method:

```
public int indexOfValue(E value) {  
  if (mGarbage) {
  gc();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++)
  if (mValues[i] == value)
  return i;

  return -1;
}
```

One idea would be to extend the SparseArray and override the method replacing == with equal.

```
public int indexOfValue(E value) {  
  if (mGarbage) {
  gc();
  }

  for (int i = 0; i < mSize; i++)
  if (mValues[i].equals(value))
  return i;

  return -1;
}
```